# Show that $\gamma$ is a generalized helix if and only if the binormal $b(s)$ has a constant angle $\theta$ with a fixed vector $a\neq 0$.

Tags: calculus, geometry

A regular curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb R^3$ with curvature $\kappa(t) > 0$ is a *generalized helix* if the tangent vector $t$ makes a fixed angle $\theta$ with a fixed unit vector $a$.

Now let $\gamma: (\alpha, \beta) \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ be a regular curve with curvature $\kappa$ and torsion $\tau$ never $0$.

I want to show that $\gamma$ is a generalized helix if and only if the binormal $b(s)$ makes a fixed angle $\theta$ with a fixed vector $a\neq 0$.

I know I can write $b = t \times n$ and intuitively, since $b$ is making a fixed angle $\theta$ with $a$ then $t$ must also ? How can I state this rigorously ? Could I also use this in proving the other direction ?